# Adding headers on UI action - Protractor +jasmine

Tags: angularjs-directive, jasmine, http-headers, protractor, bdd

I have a requirement to add headers to every request on UI action. so be it opening home page, click on buttons or links I need to add few headers. I need to do this in protractor so that I can automate the functionality. Can you please give me some example on how I can do this?

I am using Jasmine2 + protractor 5.1.2.....

Currently we use fiddler to add the headers to perform manual testing. We want to automate the test cases and send headers from automation instead of fiddler.